# Insert an element before another element using ID or CLASSNAME

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to move an element before another element? Like example shown below, I need move #child before `#parent`. There are already some `div`s exist before and after the #parent, so `append` and `prepend` won't work. After and before only take strings. However, the parent and child both have a lot content so I can't just copy them to JavaScript.

```
<div id="container">
  //many other existing divs 

  <div id="parent">
     <div id="child"></div>
  </div>

  //many other existing divs
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

> Insert every element in the set of matched elements before the target.

*Code*

```
$('#child').insertBefore('#parent')
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('#child').insertBefore('#parent')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div>many other existing divs
  </div>

  <div id="parent">
    parent
    <div id="child">child</div>
  </div>

  <div>many other existing divs
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can also use [`.before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/)

> Insert content, specified by the parameter, before each element in the set of matched elements.

```
$("#parent").before($('#child'));
```

```js
$(function() {
  $( "#parent").before($('#child'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div>many other existing divs
  </div>

  <div id="parent">
    parent
    <div id="child">child</div>
  </div>

  <div>many other existing divs
  </div>
</div>
```

The `.before()` and `.insertBefore()` methods perform the same task. The major difference is in the syntax—specifically, in the placement of the content and target.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/)

> Insert every element in the set of matched elements before the target.

```
  $('#child').insertBefore('#parent')
```